# GLSL, HLSL Шейдер из нескольких файлов

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, шейдеры

Например есть 3 шейдера. параллакс, бамп, и солид. В каждом шейдере должны быть общие вычисления типа вычисления источников света.

Реально ли в GLSL и HLSL вынести эти функции в отдельный файл и потом их как бы подключать как .h файл к коду программы?
Каковы конструкции, ключевые слова в шейдерных языках и что нужно сделать в коде программы для того чтобы их использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько мне видится, самым универсальным решением для HLSL и GLSL может быть написание своего простенького препроцессора, который будет вместо строке `#include("bump.glsl")` вставлять код этого файла.

Также можно пытаться обойтись дефайнами и таким образом отключать или включать какие-то функции в шейдере.

P.S. В вопросе наверное стоило указать версию GLSL и HLSL, которую вы планируете использовать.